# Using Fourier transform to calculating the average of the power spectrum

Tags: matlab, continuous-fourier

I want to know is there any way to write a code for this expression?
I don't know how I can define `t'` in this expression.
on the other hand the integration varies from `-inf` to `+inf`.

[image]

Comment: You may be getting confused between the Fourier Transform and the Discrete Fourier Transform ? (Or do you really want the Fourier Transform of a continuous analytic function ?)

Comment: Yes, I want Fourier Transform of a continuous analytic function.

Comment: Ok. Well, now what?
How can I solve my problem? 
Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure if MATLAB is even the right tool for the job - I only really use it for numerical work and I have no idea what it's capable of if you need to do symbolic maths.

Comment: No, It's not a symbolic maths.
All parameters have numerical values, and I have them.
But the problem is how I can write this equation for them.